# Automatically recreate a lot of different links to renamed directories or files

Tags: linux, perl, shell, solaris, ksh

I need to rename a lot of  directories and files in my Linux/Solaris machines.
There are many links that pointed to those directories/files.

So first I create the following script in order to find all directories that I want to rename (like `DOMAIN.city.country`,  `DOMAIN.type.country` etc.)
and their links.

The script takes the old and new names of the node from file `info.file` file. The first field in each line represents the old directory name and the second field represents the new directory name.

File `find_and_recreate_link_to_new_dir.ksh`

```
while read -r line ; do 

[[ -z $line ]] && continue

name_old_dir=` echo $line | awk '{print $1}' `
name_new_dir=` echo $line | awk '{print $2}' `

find / -type l -exec ls -l 2>/dev/null '{}' \; |  perl -ne'BEGIN { $str = shift(@ARGV); }     print if /\Q$str\E/; ' $name_old_dir

done  < /tmp/test/info.file
```

File `/tmp/test/info.file`

```
    DOMAIN.city.country DOMAIN.world.country
    DOMAIN.city1.country DOMAIN.world1.country
    ...
```

When I run my script I get this output

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:22 /var/test/info.domain2.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:22 /var/test/info.domain.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:22 /var/test/info.domain1.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Mar 15 11:57 /var/test/DOMAIN.type.country -> mkdir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:58 /var/test/info.tyep.com -> DOMAIN.type.country
...
```

Now I need to add to this script a section that will recreate the current links to the new directories. For example

```
/var/test/info.domain2.com -> DOMAIN.world.country
```

Please advise the best solution to automatically recreate the current links to the new directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem properly, you want to create symbolic links based on the information coming from `find_and_recreate_link_to_new_dir.ksh`.

So if you get

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:22 /var/test/info.domain2.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
```

you will want to create the link

```
/var/test/info.domain2.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
```

In this case, what I recommend you is to store both parameters and call `ln -s` with them. It can be interesting to save data in a file, let's say FILE_WITH_NEW_DATA:

```
find / -type l -exec ls -l 2>/dev/null '{}' \; |  perl -ne'BEGIN { $str = shift(@ARGV); }     print if /\Q$str\E/; ' $name_old_dir >> FILE_WITH_NEW_DATA
```

Then, given the string

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 15 11:22 /var/test/info.domain2.com -> DOMAIN.city.country
```

you can get the parameters with:

```
link = $(awk 'N=NF-2 {print $N}')
file = $(awk '{print $NF}')
```

and then create the symbolic link with `ln -s $file $link`.

All together,

```
... 

find / -type l -exec ls -l 2>/dev/null '{}' \; |  perl -ne'BEGIN { $str = shift(@ARGV); }     print if /\Q$str\E/; ' $name_old_dir >> FILE_WITH_DATA

...


while read -r line ; do 

  [[ -z $line ]] && continue

  link = $(echo $line | awk 'N=NF-2 {print $N}')
  file = $(echo $line | awk '{print $NF}')

  # begin OPTION 1) we delete previous link
  rm $link
  ln -s $file $link
  # end OPTION 1)

  # begin OPTION 2) we force the link to be created and replace the older one
  ln -s -f $file $link
  # end OPTION 2)

done  < FILE_WITH_NEW_DATA
```

Comment: the target is to re-create the current link ( for example ) /var/test/info.domain2.com to the new folder - DOMAIN.world.country , according to info.file

Comment: OK, then you should delete the link firstly and then re-create it. Let's just add `rm $link` rior to the `ln -s` creation.

Comment: is it possible other way without rm ?

Comment: Well, you can also use the `-f` force way with `ln`. This way it would be `ln -s -f $file $link` and will change the existing one.

Comment: I updated my post with both options. Have in mind that when you have a soft link, if you delete it, the linked file is not affected. But be careful if it is a hard link, which would perform differently!

Comment: find / -name -l ( this command not search the hard link ) , so why be worry ? , no chance to found hard link only soft link

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not very efficient.  For each file to be mapped, it runs `awk` twice (which is a minor peccadillo compared with what follows), and then runs `find` on the entire machine looking for symlinks, and runs `ls` for each symlink, only selecting the links where the old name shows up.

Traversing the entire file system is excruciatingly slow; you can only afford to do it once.

I think you should use a more complex Perl script (since you're already using Perl) to do most of the work, but you can keep the `find` command though it would also be possible to use Perl's File::Find (core) module.

The Perl script would be given the mapping file (`/tmp/test/info.file`) as an argument, and the symlinks from your `find` command:

- Read the lines from the file
- Rename the files accordingly
- Also record old name and new name in a hash for mapping
- Read standard input for symlink names
- Use readlink to read the target of the symlink
- If the link matches any of the old names

  - Remove the old link
  - Create the new link

The shell script becomes:

```
find / -type l -print | perl rebuild.links.pl /tmp/test/info.file
```

The Perl script becomes (warning — untested code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %map;

die "Usage: $0 map-file\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open $ARGV[0] for reading\n";
    while (<$fh>)
    {
        chomp;
        next if m/^\s*$/;  # Skip blank lines
        next if m/^#/;     # Skip comment lines
        my($old, $new) = split /\s+/, $_;
        if (-f $old)
        {
            $map{$old} = $new;
            rename $old, $new or die "Failed to rename $old to $new\n";
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

shift @ARGV;  # Lose the file name

# Read standard input for symlink names
while (my $source = <>)
{
     chomp $source;
     my $oldlink = readlink $_;
     MAP:
     for my $old (keys %map)
     {
         if ($oldlink =~ m%$old%)
         {
             my $target = $oldlink;
             $target =~ s%$old%$map{$old}%;
             die "Mapped name $target does not exist for symlink $source (old link $oldlink)\n"
                 unless -e $target;
             unlink $source or die "Failed to remove symlink $source\n";
             symlink $target, $source or die "Failed to create symlink $source for $target\n";
             last MAP;
         }
     }
}
```

The code shown compiles (`perl -c`) but has not been run.  Treat it as an improved outline of what I think your code should look like.  Issues that you should make sure you understand before you even think of testing it include:

- Are the names in the `/tmp/test/info.file` correct when processed by this script?  Are they absolute names, or are they simple names relative to the current directory?
- Will the mappings shown work correctly?

For debugging the code, I'd probably:

- Add `use constant debug => 1;` at the top.
- Print instead of execute `unlink`, `symlink`, `rename`, etc with the condition `if debug;`.
- Run the `find` command over a sub-directory instead of `/` until I was sure I knew what was going on.

Be careful — this is dangerous stuff.

Comment: in my perl command ( in find ) i Use Q and E in order to ignore the "." char ( like \. ) , but I not see this option in your code

Comment: True; I worked on the (perhaps optimistic) assumption that you don't need to map `DOMAIN.city.country` to `DOMAIN.world.country` without mapping `DOMAINxcityxcountry` to anything.  That is, the chances of the `.` acting like a regex `.` and screwing up the matches is negligible to non-existent.  If that's a problem, then you need to be careful.  As I said, it is only an untested outline; it is not 'working code'.